# Parcel not distributed but have active state ACTIVATING

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

In my **Cloudera manager 5.4.7**, I tried to distribute the spark package using **parcels**, but got stuck at `activating 0%`.

The error message stated `Parcel not distributed but have active state ACTIVATING`. It seems to be in an inconsistent state.

By searching the error message on Google, I followed instructions [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Parcel-not-distributed-but-have-active-state-ACTIVATING/td-p/28230) to use the Cloudera API to force deactivation, but it did not work either (with `405 Method not allowed` HTTP response code).

The API I tried are as follows:
http://master:7180/api/v10/clusters/myCluster/parcels/products/SPARK/versions/0.9.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.98 (this worked fine and returned a JSON object)
http://master:7180/api/v10/clusters/myCluster/parcels/products/SPARK/versions/0.9.0-1.cdh4.6.0.p0.98/commands/deactivate (this returned HTTP code 405)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution in case anyone is having the same problem. See the solution at [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Cloudera-Manager-Installation/Parcel-not-distributed-but-have-active-state-ACTIVATING/m-p/32474). Basically you should use `curl -X POST` with Cloudera API.